# React Redux stored array of object and shouldComponentUpdate

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am a beginner in react-redux, and I created a dashboard to show items stored in a database to develop skills.

In my reducer I have the full list of items stored in a global state item : "itemsList". Each item has a complex structure, with some arrays into them for example.

The dashboard view simply displays the full range of the itemsList in an table.

Every second an API request is done updating the full array of items.

My problem is that each time the api request is processed, the dashboard is rendered again. I've read about shouldComponentUpdate combined with componentWillReceiveProps to be able to tell if a new render is needed, but I don't think it is the right way to do it and in my componentWillReceiveProps, the props seems to be already updated...

Do you have any advice on a way to do it better ?

Sorry for my poor english...

Thank you

Comment: If your data is being updated everytime you make a new api request, then you must do a new render everytime. React will make the least amount of changes in the DOM, so check if items that did not get updated in the list are being re-rendered (they should not). Install the React Developer Tools in your browser and check the "Highlight Updates" option. That way you will be able to spot every update that is being made to the DOM.

Comment: If you want to prevent re-renders because the data did not change, then implementing the shouldComponentUpdate function is the way to go. If you could share some of your component code, maybe it would be easier to spot a possible performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

Any time your `itemsList` will update, it will trigger a full re-render of your component.

The idea with React is to have separation of concerns. From what you are saying, you should split up your `itemsList` since it is the only thing that is in your app and the only thing that changes.

Maybe rework your data structure to better reflect what needs to update less and what updates more.